# Lifts of geodesics on surfaces onto the universal cover

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, surfaces

[self-intersecting geodesic on hyperbolic surface of genus 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgpHf.png)

Given a self intersecting geodesic on a hyperbolic surface of genus 2 as in the picture, how can I understand precisely what the lift to the universal cover looks like? I understand that the lift will be an infinite number of geodesics in $\mathbb{H}^{2} $ (I'm visualising the Poincare disk model). I understand these geodesics will intersect transversely, with only two geodesics intersecting at one point. I guess I would like to know for instance how this would look as opposed to having a similar geodesic immersed into a genus 3 hyperbolic hyperbolic surface instead or if I just chose a different geodesic. Also, will the fundamental group of the genus 2 surface act transitively on the geodesics in the universal cover?

Comment: Not research level, and not clear what you are asking.